# How to check if an account from username and password has admin rights/privileges?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am wondering if in python is it possible, given the strings `username` and `password`, find out if that account has admin rights?

For example, if I have two `input`s:

```
u = input("Username: ")
p = input("Password: ")

# hasAdminRights is a placeholder to checking if the account first of all exists, and then if it has admin.

if hasAdminRights(u,p):
    print "This account has admin privileges!"
else:
    print """This account either
    1) does not have admin
    2) is not a real account
    3) entered the wrong password"""
```

I need to be able to check this even if the logged in user is not an admin.

I have seen many stackoverflow questions on checking if the current user has admin, but I would like to check if a different user on the pc has admin.

Thanks in advance,

David Callanan

Comment: Perhaps, I'm missing something however it is unclear what system/application/software you are referring to. Are you speaking of building your own permissions system, or checking another pre-existing system(s)? If so what system?

Comment: @CopyandPaste I am just creating a program to check and tell you if an account that exists on a computer has admin rights or not, so you can find out which accounts do have admin.

Comment: On a computer? Are you referring to a windows/linux/mac login for a particular operating system?

Comment: @CopyandPaste for windows

Comment: What versions of windows will this have to support. Also please add this to the first question.

Comment: Maybe this can help you start off: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/check-a-users-credentials.html

Comment: has to support Windows 7

Comment: @CopyandPaste This looks good however according to the link you will need os privleges to run the code, which the logged in user won't have. Only the typed in user will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an access token for the user, call `LogonUser`, which hasn't required `SeTcbPrivilege` since Windows XP/2003. Next call `GetTokenInformation` to get the elevation type, linked token, and the list of groups in the token. For example:

```
from win32security import (
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, SE_GROUP_ENABLED,
    TokenElevationType, TokenLinkedToken, TokenGroups,
    TokenElevationTypeLimited, WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid,
    LogonUser, GetTokenInformation, CreateWellKnownSid)

def is_user_an_admin(username, password, allow_elevation=True):
    token = LogonUser(username, None, password,
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
    elevation_type = GetTokenInformation(token, TokenElevationType)
    admin_group = CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid)
    if elevation_type == TokenElevationTypeLimited and allow_elevation:
        linked_token = GetTokenInformation(token, TokenLinkedToken)
        token_list = [token, linked_token]
    else:
        token_list = [token]
    for token in token_list:
        for group, attrs in GetTokenInformation(token, TokenGroups):
            enabled = attrs & SE_GROUP_ENABLED
            if enabled and group == admin_group:
                return True
    return False
```

This example doesn't mask exceptions, such as for an incorrect password.

Comment: Thanks this nearly works however are you able to use this on networks.

Comment: You didn't state that the username is in UPN format (e.g. username@example.com) or fully qualified (e.g. server.domain.com\\username).

Comment: I forgot to include that in the question. If a user on the network "NETWORK_NAME" runs this program and inputs the username "example", do you know if this will look for "NETWORK_NAME\example"?

Comment: As written this function is limited to looking up accounts on the local machine of the caller, unless a domain user name is supplied in UPN format with a DNS domain name.